# Different behavior in Jersey tests

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

I have a service implemented using Jersey that write/read from a JSON file and I have a test file extending JerseyTest class for testing that service.

What I am trying to do is when running the test it write/read in a different file (with '_test' in name). That way I don't have the values changed from the main file.

The file is being instanced in the @PostConstruct method like that:

```java
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    try {
        jsonFile = new NewsJson(); // Need to have a different behavior for testing
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        LOGGER.error("Error creating file: " + ioe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

What I have tried is to call a @POST method that modify the jsonFile variable, activating writting in a different file. The problem in that solution is the @PostConstruct method being called every request.

How can I change that behavior? Is there a different annotation for initializing services using Jersey?

Comment: Do you really want to initialize the file in a construct? Why can't you create this file in your POST operation itself? 

You can differentiate test vs production requests based on some HTTP header and change creation of jsonFile?

Answer (score 0):

And to add to my comment, since this looks like answer :

If you really want to have it constructed only once change scope to @Scope("singleton") that will cause the jersey "bean" to instantiate once instead of per request.

Comment: In this case, how can I handle multiple concurrent requests?

Answer (score 0):

I got an acceptable solution. The idea to add a header param for every request helped a lot. I created a super class called Service having a header param, like that:

```java
@HeaderParam("testing")
private boolean testing;
```

After that I created too a method isTesting() to get the value of this variable. So in my service (NewsService) I extends the super class Service and on it @PostConstruct method I did this:

```java
if (isTesting()) {
    jsonFile = new NewsJson(NewsJson.TEST_FILE);
} else {
    jsonFile = NoticiaJson();
}
```

All i had to change were my unit tests methods, adding a header variable on the request:

```java
webResource.header("testing", true)
```

Comment: Ok, that's what I meant in my comment initially.